# How to use resque-scheduler and resque-status together?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, resque

I have **resque-scheduler** working fine in a rails app. Now I need to be able to **track status and remove jobs** from the queue. I had a brief look at **resque-status** and, from what I saw, if I could get it to play nicely with resque-scheduler then it would be perfect.

However, it seems rescue-status uses `create` which wraps `enqueue` and resque-scheduler uses the extended `enqueue_at` which I am using currently. Is there an easy way to get them to play together without too much hacking of the plugins? Has anyone done this already and would be willing to give me some hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

resque-scheduler 1.9.6 now supports custom job types including the latest version of resque-status.  Upgrade both gems and check out the readme for resque-scheduler on how to set it up.

Comment: What's the right way to pass parameters to Resque::JobWithStatus by Resque.set_schedule ?